# VMs not starting on KVM after reboot

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have 2 VMs running on Ubuntu server 16.04 that are not starting after reboot. I have configured them to autostart.

When I tried starting the VMs virsh start VM, I receive the following error:

error: Failed to start domain vpre06
error: Device 0000:3b:02.0 not found: could not access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:3b:02.0/config: No such file or directory

The device 0000:3b:02.0 (pci)is from an Intel 10G Ethernet card and I can see the 0000:3b:02.0 device when I type lspci -nnkv.

This is what used to create the VM:

root@MYR-EQX-SYD-DPISRV-02:~# virt-install --connect qemu:///system --name=vpre06 --memory=160000 --vcpus=32,placement="static" --os-type=linux --os-variant=virtio26 --disk path=/data/VM/vpre06/vpre06-disk1.qcow2,format=qcow2,bus=virtio,cache=none --cpu host-passthrough --memorybacking hugepages=on,nosharepages=on,size=1,unit=G  --network bridge=br_admin,model=virtio --network bridge=br_aux,model=virtio --host-device=3b:02.0 --host-device=3b:06.0 --host-device=3b:0a.0 --host-device=3b:0e.0 --host-device=5e:02.0 --host-device=5e:06.0 --host-device=5e:0a.0 --host-device=5e:0e.0 --host-device=60:02.0 --host-device=60:06.0 --host-device=60:0a.0 --host-device=60:0e.0 --memballoon none --nographics --noautoconsole --import

Comment: That PCI device that you tried to passthrough to the VM has been removed or moved to a different slot. Or the BIOS was updated and it rearranged the PCI bus.

Comment: Apologies for the late response,Thanks Michael.